# Using Firebase Dynamic Links for dev bundle id on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

For my iOS app, the dev project has a different bundle id than the prod app.

Because the dev app isn't published, and therefore has no Store ID, the Dynamic Links SDK returns an error:

> Your project does not own Dynamic Links domain

Is there any way to use test the Firebase Dynamic Links SDK with my dev bundle ID?

Comment: I'm using it with no problem, i use if for email validation (on a register screen) and the link is working properly. Can you post the error ?

Comment: Just added the error text. You're using it on a bundle id that isn't published to the store? If I change no code at all and just use my prod (published) bundle id, it works no problem

Comment: Yes I'm using in without the app been published. But if your have a different bundle id then you have to create a different project on firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the Dynamic Link first through Firebase Console for you to create Dynamic Links programmatically. See this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create#set-up-firebase-and-the-dynamic-links-sdk) for more info.